# Powershell show ports connection and filter only closed ports

Tags: powershell, port

I have this little scrip.

```
$portnumbers=2000,2001,80,81,21,30300,30301,30302,30303,6000,6001,6002,600
$Ipaddress= "127.0.0.1"
foreach($p in $portnumbers ){
Test-OpenPort -Port $p | Select port,status | Format-Table
}
```

the output is :

```
Port Status
---- ------
2000  False

Port Status
---- ------
2001  False

Port Status
---- ------
  80   True

Port Status
---- ------
  81  False


Port Status
---- ------
  21  False


 Port Status
 ---- ------
30300  False
```

i would like to get this result is different way , when port is closed so i want receive some massage port "Portnumber" is closed - in a red color
and when it open , port " portnumber" is open .

and then massage that say " this is the closed ports : "
like summery .

can you please help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mathias beat me to it, but if you also would like a summary of the closed ports, then capture the closed results of the loop in a variable and display afterwards.

Something like

```
$closed = foreach($p in $portnumbers ){
    $result = Test-OpenPort -Port $p
    if ($result.Status) { Write-Host "Port $p is open" }
    else { Write-Host "Port $p is closed" -ForegroundColor Red ; $p}
}

# summary
"`r`nThese ports are closed:`r`n{0}" -f ($closed -join "`r`n")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Write-Host` with the `-ForegroundColor` parameter:

```
Write-Host "Port 123 is closed!" -ForgroundColor Red
```

To select different background colors and message based on the `Status` property value, you could use a simple `if` statement inside the loop:

```
$portnumbers=2000,2001,80,81,21,30300,30301,30302,30303,6000,6001,6002,600
$Ipaddress= "127.0.0.1"
foreach($p in $portnumbers ){
    $portTestResult = Test-OpenPort -Port $p | Select Port,Status
    if($portTestResult.Status){
        Write-Host "Port $p is open" -ForegroundColor Green
    }
    else{
        Write-Host "Port $p is closed" -ForegroundColor Red
    }
}
```

Comment: What is it mean by $portTestResult.Status , what is the status mean ? closed , open ? how does it know if it open or close ?

Comment: I'm saving the output of `Test-OpenPart -Port $p |Select Port,Status` to a variable `$portTestResult` - I'm assuming the `Status` property indicate whether the port was open or not? So if the `Status` is `$true` (ie. the tested port is open), we write in green that it was open, otherwise that it's closed (in red)

Comment: Thank  you million times !! helped a lot !

Comment: i tried to do the same thing with features and it wont work :( 




$windowsfeaturslist = "NET-Framework-Features" , "NET-Framework-Core" , "NET-HTTP-Activation" , "NET-Non-HTTP-Activ" , "NET-Framework-45-Features" 
foreach ($featurename in $windowsfeaturslist) {

Get-WindowsFeature -Name $featurename
if($test.'Install State'){
Write-Host "not installed" -ForegroundColor Red
}
else{
Write-Host "installed" -ForegroundColor Green
}
$featurename = $null
}

Comment: @Simba You need to assign the output from `Get-WindowsFeature` to `$test` if you want to use that to store the result